# How to automatically mark through a quiz with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-applications

I have been trying to write a code that automatically brings the answer to the summer of correct and incorrect options checked ??
Here is my code i tried looping through the whole question and nesting my loop to add 1 to sum if the option checked is correct

```
<!-- HTML CODE--->
<ol class="question"> 
  <li id="question1"> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="1"> Okeke </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0"> Lolaoluwa </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0"> Offisong </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0"> Offong </input>
  </li> 
  <li id="question2"> 
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="1"> Marvellous </input> 
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="1"> Johnpaul </input> 
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="0"> Emmanuel </input> 
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="0"> Abigail </input>
   </li> 
   <li id="question3"> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0"> Phoebe </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0"> Ross </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="1"> Chandler </input> 
     <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0"> Joey </input>
   </li>
   <button onclick="box()" > Click me</button>
</ol>

 <!-- js CODE--->
function box() { 
     var things $("ol.question li").eq(i); 
     for (var i = 1; i < 3 ; i++) {
          $("ol.question li").eq(i); 
                for (var j = 1 ; j < 4; j++){ 
                     var textNode = $("input[type='radio']").eq(j); 
                 sum =0;
                   if(textNode.checked == true){
                       sum = sum + textNode.checked().value(); 
                       alert(sum);
                   }
               }
        }
     }
```

Comment: how do you checked if the answer is correct ? i.e: where `value="1"` is right answer ?

Comment: Yes value = 1 is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse through `<li>` and see which radio button is checked and compare its value with `1` if value is `1` increment `sum+1` .

**Demo code** :

```js
function box() {
  let sum = 0;
  //traverse through li-> radio button which is checked
  $('li input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
  //if value of checked is 1
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      sum = sum + 1; //increment sum
    }
  });
  //print on console
  console.log("Total score - " + sum)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="question">
  <li id="question1">
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="1" /> Okeke
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0" /> Lolaoluwa
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0" /> Offisong
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="grp1" value="0" /> Offong
  </li>
  <li id="question2">
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="1" /> Marvellous
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="1" /> Johnpaul
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="0" /> Emmanuel
    <input type="radio" name="grp2" id="grp2" value="0" /> Abigail
  </li>
  <li id="question3">
    <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0" /> Phoebe
    <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0" /> Ross
    <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="1" /> Chandler
    <input type="radio" name="grp3" id="grp3" value="0" /> Joey
  </li>
  <button onclick="box()"> Click me</button>
</ol>
```